# How do I block a blogspot site using hosts file?

Tags: safe-browsing

I have a blogspot site, say `ABC.blogspot.com` which I want to block. When I add the following in my `/etc/hosts` file, it has no effect:

```
127.0.0.1 ABC.blogspot.com
```

The site still loads as usual. Can someone help me out? Why is this not working?

Comment: Your browser probably has its own DNS cache, which is skipping the OS-level resolver. Try Ctrl+F5 to force refresh, or restart your system.

Comment: Are you on a network that is using a proxy server?

Comment: Check /etc/nsswitch.conf too